# Hover Focus exceeding the ListViewItem width in UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple horizontal `ListView` where it will show trending anime. It is a horizontal ListView. But as in this image, in the One-Piece anime, the hover is present. but due to screenshot, the hover is hidden. when the hovered `ListViewItem` is focused, it is showing some extra sapces on both sides of the main element, How do I rectify it??

[image]

Any Ideas...

My ListView is below:

```xml
<ListView ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                              ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              x:Name="AnimeTrendingList"
                              ItemClick="AnimeTrendingList_ItemClick"
                              UseSystemFocusVisuals="False">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                           
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MediaElement">
                                    <Grid 
                              Width="150"
                                    Height="300"
                              CornerRadius="10">
                                        <Grid.ContextFlyout>
                                            <MenuFlyout>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem 
                                                x:Name="AnimeSaveImage" 
                                                Text="Save Image" 
                                                Click="AnimeSaveImage_Click"
                                                Tag="{x:Bind CoverImage.ExtraLarge.AbsoluteUri}"/>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem 
                                                x:Name="AnilistUrlCopy" 
                                                Text="Copy AniList URL"
                                                Click="AnilistUrlCopy_Click"
                                                Tag="{x:Bind SiteUrl.ToString()}"/>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem
                                                x:Name="AnilistOpenUrl"
                                                Text="Open in Browser"
                                                Click="AnilistOpenUrl_Click"
                                                Tag="{x:Bind SiteUrl.ToString()}"/>
                                                <MenuFlyoutItem 
                                                    x:Name="EmbedableBannerSave"
                                                    Text="Save Embeddable Image"
                                                    Click="EmbedableBannerSave_Click"
                                                    Tag="{x:Bind Id.ToString()}"/>
                                            </MenuFlyout>
                                        </Grid.ContextFlyout>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Width="150">
                                            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{x:Bind CoverImage.Large.AbsoluteUri}"/>
                                                </Image.Source>
                                            </Image>
                                            <!--<Canvas ToolTipService.ToolTip="Currently Airing">
                                    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="5"
                                               Canvas.Left="5"
                                               Width="25"
                                               Height="25"
                                               Fill="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicInAppLuminosity}"/>
                                    <Ellipse Width="15"
                                             Height="15"
                                             Canvas.Left="10"
                                             Canvas.Top="10"
                                             Fill="LightGreen"/>
                                </Canvas>-->
                                        </Grid>
                                        <StackPanel 
                                        Width="150"
                                                Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltLowColor}"
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            Canvas.ZIndex="2">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title.UserPreferred}"
                                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                           FontSize="15"
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Margin="5, 15, 5, 2"
                                           ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind Title.UserPreferred}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Studios.Nodes[0].Name}"
                                           FontStyle="Italic"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Margin="5, 0, 5, 5"
                                           Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemBaseMediumHighColor}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind sys:String.Format(x:Null, '{0} • {1} Episodes', Format, Episodes)}"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           Margin="5, 2, 5, 5"/>
                                            <Grid Margin="5, 0">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="5">
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE249;"
                                                  FontSize="12"
                                                  Foreground="Yellow"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Trending.ToString()}"
                                                   FontSize="12"
                                                   Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Margin="5"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE00B;"
                                                  FontSize="12"
                                                  Foreground="Red"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Favourites.ToString()}"
                                                   FontSize="12"
                                                   Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Comment: I see you have a main grid which represents the entirety of the datatemplate, and then within that are a) grid for contextFlyout, b) grid for the image and c) a stackpanel. the main grid has no rows defined, so behavior later on will be unpredictable.

Comment: Additionally: the artwork has different dimensions, width and corner radius than what you defined for the main grid.  The mouseover will highllight the extent of the dataTemplate so the options are to: make the items within fit (or stretch) to the extent of the template item or define a different mouseover behavior. for example: imagine if you wanted to only apply a border brush to your image, and not the stackpanel...can you upload a sample of the artwork used for repro?

Comment: What's the  extra sapces when item focus you mentioned above ?

Comment: see the ONE PIECE section, there will be white shades on both the sides

Comment: The dimensions of the content are narrower than that of the data template item. pointerEntered will highlight to the extent of the datatemplate; which looks odd when one expects the content to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hover Focus exceeding the ListViewItem width in UWP C#

It looks the default ListViewItem background, and it will highlight when point over or point pressed. you could set them as `Transparent` to disable this behavior. please refer to the following code taht place in the app resource dictionary.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPressed" Color="Transparent" />
</Application.Resources>
```